# How to add child keywords through coreservice

Tags: core-service

I have a problem that when I try to add keywords to a parent keyword it add's it to the category instead (This because the webdav url is /Category/Keyword instead of /Category/ParentKeyword/Keyword)

Now I found that you have to create a LinkToKeywordData but when i try the following code, it will throw a nullpointerexception on the getWebdavUrl setvalue. What is the correct way of getting a LinkToKeywordData and ArrayOfLinkToKeywordData?

```
ArrayOfLinkToKeywordData array = new ArrayOfLinkToKeywordData();
for(Keyword parent : keyword.getParents()){
     LinkToKeywordData link = new LinkToKeywordData();
     link.getWebDavUrl().setValue(parent.getWebdavUrl());
     array.getLinkToKeywordData().add(link);
}
keywordData.getParentKeywords().setValue(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
KeywordData keyword = (KeywordData)channel.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Keyword, "[CategoryId]", new ReadOptions());
keyword.Title = "Child Keyword";
keyword.Key = "Child Keyword";
keyword.ParentKeywords = new LinkToKeywordData[] { new LinkToKeywordData() { IdRef = "[ParentKeywordId]" } };

channel.Save(keyword, new ReadOptions());
```

Comment: Hmm I don't see how this would make a difference? You are still just creating a new object with all values set to null, there is no object initialization in java and you can only set values through the setValue method

Answer (score 0):

See the below code it may help you and let me know if not work

```
 public static string CreateNavigationKeyword(string title, string linkTitle,string filepath, string categoryID,string ParentKeywordID, SessionAwareCoreServiceClient client,string schemaID)
    {
        string createdKey = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            KeywordData keyword = (KeywordData)client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Keyword, categoryID);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParentKeywordID))
            {
                LinkToKeywordData[] _parentKeywords = new[] { new LinkToKeywordData { IdRef = ParentKeywordID } };
                keyword.ParentKeywords = _parentKeywords;
            }
            keyword.Id = "tcm:0-0-0";
            keyword.Title = title;
            keyword.Key = title;

            SchemaFieldsData schemaFields = client.ReadSchemaFields(schemaID, true, new ReadOptions());
            var metafields = Fields.ForMetadataOf(schemaFields, keyword);
            metafields["text"].Value = linkTitle;
            metafields["link"].Value = filepath;
            keyword.Metadata = metafields.ToString();

            createdKey = client.Create(keyword, new ReadOptions()).Id.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return createdKey;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, in Java you need to use the ObjectFactory to create the LinkToKeywordData:

```
ArrayOfLinkToKeywordData aoltk = keywordData.getParentKeywords().getValue();
        List<LinkToKeywordData> list = aoltk.getLinkToKeywordData();
        ObjectFactory of = new ObjectFactory();
        for(Keyword parent : keyword.getParents()){
            LinkToKeywordData link = of.createLinkToKeywordData();
            link.setWebDavUrl(of.createLinkWebDavUrl(parent.getWebdavUrl()));
            aoltk.getLinkToKeywordData().add(link);
        }
        keywordData.getParentKeywords().setValue(aoltk)
```